# Adding VF page to an Object's related list in the page layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject, standard-objects

We can add VF pages to an Object's page layout.

But when we add any visualforce page to the layout then we are only restricted to add only between the EDIT & DELETE buttons of the object layout.

But my requirement is to add it where Related lists of that particular object is started not as shown in the image.

[image]

Is it possible? OR Anyone tried this ?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kapil Kaushik

Comment: a screen shot of what you are trying to do would focus the answers

Comment: hv u tried the inline vf page? you need to create a vf page with standard controller then only that page will be display in edit pagelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in Salesforce Classic and if we talk about the salesforce lightning then the visualfocre page itself shown in the separate section for any record's detail page which is called 'DETAILS'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use standard controllers and for this (in the VF page).

[**THIS**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_custom_mapping.htm) and [**THIS**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) may help.

You will also need to define a standard controller extension, if you want to have custom logic in your controller.

Dont worry, its quite easy, take a look at [**THIS**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_sample.htm) to see how to make extensions. The post also deals with related lists, but not in the way you want, hence, you will need to read and understand the concept and figure out a solution on your own.

There are many answers/blogs/search results for this problem, I googled for `add visualforce page to related list` and the links I mentioned were in the top 5 results.